# How to Remove Previously Saved messages from ModelState in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate

i have a question about modelstate in asp.net mvc3 that , i have a contoller suppose `Home` and a action in it `submitform` . now first time i submit my form to this action and user entered someting wrong i returened error using modelstate

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your entered date is wrong .");
```

Now when user submit form again this time suppose date is correct but he entered wrong name this time , now when i return error at this step

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "name should be at least 4 character long .");
```

but now when i return this i see `name should be at least 4 character long .` and  also see  `Your entered date is wrong.` , what the problem ?

following is my full code

```
   [Authorize]
[System.Web.Mvc.OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
       public ActionResult Formsubmit(mymodel RModel)
       {
          if(RModel.date != "2/2/2012")
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your entered date is wrong .");
           }
           if(RModel.name.cout() < 4)
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError("", "name should be at least 4 character long .");

           }

           return View(RModel);
       } 
}
```

Comment: Please show your full controller/action method code.

Comment: Is the value of RModel.date property fixed to "2/2/2012"? If the value of RModel.date is null or anything else, it should add the 'date is wrong...' error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Modelstate.Remove("yourkey"); //remove one

Modelstate.Clear(); //remove all
```

Answer (score 1):

Use named error massges. This give you ability to clean up them:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("WrongData", "Your entered date is wrong .");
```

later

```
ModelState.AddModelError("WrongData", ""); //clear error message
ModelState.AddModelError("WrongLenth", "name should be at least 4 character long .");
```

as a bonus if you for some reason decided to show some error message 2 times you may do this as well:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("WrongData", "Your entered date is wrong .");
ModelState.AddModelError("WrongData2", "Your entered date is wrong .");
```

Comment: but i previously entered one error with out name , so now how can i delete that ?